# MariaDB 11 fails to start: [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Unable to find charset-collation for 15

Tags: mariadb, upgrade

after performing an upgrade from MariaDB 10.11 to 11.0.1 on AlmaLinux 9.1 MariaDB fails to start when I set my datadir to the location of our old MariaDB 10.11 databases:

```
2023-04-13 12:37:55 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.0.1-MariaDB source revision 158a58245813b1959d6ee912d77734620c7cf3ba as process 14188
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]:
2023-04-13 12:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]:
2023-04-13 12:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]:
2023-04-13 12:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]:
2023-04-13 12:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]:
2023-04-13 12:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]:
2023-04-13 12:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]:
2023-04-13 12:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=512 bytes)
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]:
2023-04-13 12:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Upgrading the change buffer
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]:
2023-04-13 12:37:55 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Unable to find charset-collation for 15
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]: 230413 12:37:55 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
Apr 13
12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]: This could be because you hit a
> bug. It is also possible that this binary
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]: or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]: or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]: To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]: We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]: diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
Apr 13 12:37:55 mariadb2pre mariadbd[14188]: something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
```

If I don't set the datadir MariaDB 11 starts.
I tried to set different InnoDB Recovery Modes but it didn't work.
How can I find and fix the wrong charset-collation if this is the problem?

Comment: How did you perform the upgrade ?  Did you run **mariadb-upgrade** ?

Comment: please do a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/).

Comment: I found a similar recently reported bug [MDEV-31443](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31443). It would have been really nice to have a bug report pre-release so some attempt to resolve could have been performed. Please help free software projects by reporting bugs.

Comment: @RohitGupta How do you run mariadb-upgrade if the server doesn't start?

Answer (score 3):

In MariaDB and MySQL, be cautious about pre-GA releases.  They are not for the faint of heart.  10.11.1 would be such a case.  Suggest 10.11.2 or 10.10.3 or the latest 10.6.xx, which will be "LTS" meaning that it will be supported for 6 years (until 2026).

Meanwhile, you could help them by filing a bug report about the collation problem.  Certainly do this if it also occurs in a GA version.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB
https://endoflife.date/mariadb
https://mariadb.org/about/#maintenance-policy

https://jira.mariadb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

In MySQL 8.0:

```
show collation where id=15;
+------------------+---------+----+---------+----------+---------+---------------+
| Collation        | Charset | Id | Default | Compiled | Sortlen | Pad_attribute |
+------------------+---------+----+---------+----------+---------+---------------+
| latin1_danish_ci | latin1  | 15 |         | Yes      |       1 | PAD SPACE     |
+------------------+---------+----+---------+----------+---------+---------------+
```

Is that available in your MariaDB 10 (previously) or 11 (attempting to upgrade to)?  And, do you have table using latin1_danish_ci with PAD_SPACE or utf8mb4_la_0900_ai_ci ?

Comment: I got a similar crash, and 11.0.2 is GA... https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31579.

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug report.  I added to my Answer and the bug.

Comment: I can confirm upgrading to 11.0.3 fixed the issue for me.